# Graphics.DrawString highlight specific words

Tags: c#, graphics, highlight, drawstring, objectlistview

I am using `Graphics.DrawString` in an [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). I need to highlight some words in the string (make their background yellow). Can this be done?

Before using `Graphics.DrawString`, I could use `DefaultRenderer` for highlighting. But now it doesn't work.

I am using `Graphics.DrawString` as in the `Task List` sample [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/samples.html)

Answer (score 5):

If ObjectListView supports it (the normal ListView certainly does)), simply use the `TextRenderer` to draw text :

[image]

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    TextFormatFlags flags =  TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,  e.Item.Text, Font, e.Bounds,
                          Color.Blue, Color.LightSteelBlue, flags);
}
```

As usual only one style is supported per call. So to highlight certain words you will have use more than one call and also use the `TextRenderer.MeasureText` method to find the next positions. It will be rather hard to get this pixel-perfect, unless you can settle for a fixed-font..

Here is a quick and dirty example:

[image]

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    TextFormatFlags flags =  TextFormatFlags.Left;

    int leftPadding = 3;
    int x = leftPadding;
    var words = e.Item.Text.Split('#');
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(x, e.Bounds.Top );
        Size sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(words[i], Font);
        if (i % 2 == 0 )
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, words[i], Font, pt, 
                                  Color.Black, flags);
        else
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, words[i], Font, pt,
                                  Color.Blue, Color.LightSteelBlue, flags);
        x += sz.Width;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is some extra space after the chinks. Maybe using the `E.Graphics.MeasureString` call wih the `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` would be better, as it is tuned to creating sizes without slack..:

**Update:**

This looks better, making us of both renderers:

[image]

```
Point pt = new Point(x, e.Bounds.Top );
Size sz1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(words[i], Font);
SizeF sz2 = e.Graphics.MeasureString(words[i],Font, 9999, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

if (i % 2 == 0 )
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, words[i], Font, pt, Color.Black);
else
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, words[i], Font, pt, 
                          Color.Blue, Color.LightSteelBlue);
x += (int )(sz1.Width + sz2.Width) / 2;
```

To draw **wrapped** text you need to take the available space into account and include the y coordinate in the calculation.. For this you can either draw word by word or use the `RenderText` overload that takes a `Rectangle`. This **will** get rather tedious!

**Update 2**

[image]

Here is another quick one showing how to handle wrapping text:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    int maxW = e.Bounds.Width;
    int leftPadding = 3;
    int leading = 1;
    int x = leftPadding;
    int y = e.Bounds.Y;
    var chunks = e.Item.Text.Split('#');

    SizeF s0 = e.Graphics.MeasureString("_|", Font);
    Size s1 = e.Bounds.Size;

    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Count(); i++)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(x, e.Bounds.Top );
        var words = chunks[i].Split(' ');

        for (int j = 0; j < words.Count(); j++)
        {
            Size sz1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(words[j], Font);
            SizeF sz2 = e.Graphics.MeasureString(words[j], Font, 9999,
                                                StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            int w = (int)(sz1.Width + sz2.Width) / 2;
            if (x + w > maxW)
            {
                y += sz1.Height + leading;
                x = leftPadding;
            }
            DrawWords(e.Graphics, words[j], Font, new Point( x, y),
                      Color.Blue, Color.LightSteelBlue, i % 2 != 1);
            x += w;
        }
    }
}
```

It uses a small function:

```
void DrawWords(Graphics g, string text, Font font, Point pt, 
               Color fCol, Color Bcol, bool highlite )
{
        if (highlite)
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, text, font, pt, Color.Black);
        else
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, text, font, pt, Color.Blue, Color.LightSteelBlue); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is supported. But I want to highlight specific words. Say all the occurrences of word1 and word2.

Comment: See my update for an example. Support for this is rather week in Winforms but still doable..

Comment: TextRenderer is *always* a better choice for rendering text. :-)

Comment: Yeah, well so I have heard. But not only have I not really really really seen it; here is a case for using at least MeasureString as well..

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and see if I can write a function that takes a list of words and highlights them.

Comment: Good luck; I have expanded the answer to include wrapping text..

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `Graphics.FillRectangle()` method for this. Hope your `ListView` doesn't wrap the text to next line.

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(yourImage.Image))
{
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    //your text starting position
    double textX = 350.0,textY=340.0;

    //Get length of one character for your font style
    float CharWidth = g.MeasureString("A", drawFont).Width;

    //Take the words before the word that has to be highlighted and get it's length
    float widthTotal = "First text strip that doesn't need highlighting".Length() * CharWidth


    //Create and draw a rectangle here offsetting this widthTotal from the starting position for the desired Length
    var size = g.MeasureString("Text to be highlighted", drawFont);
    var rectangle = new RectangleF(textX+widthTotal , textY, size.Width, size.Height);

    //Filling a rectangle before drawing the string.
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, rectangle);
    //Repeat above process for all required words

    //Finally draw your string over it
    g.DrawString("your complete text",drawFont,drawBrush,new Point(textX,textY))



}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the text is wrapped as in the example in the link in my question.